# ASP.NET Core modified URL-endpoints only work hardcoded without tag-helpers

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I've got an ASP.NET Core MVC web application (running on .NET 5). with the default 'individual authentication' template.

In the `startup.cs` I changed the standard URL to:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
  {
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
       name: "default",
       pattern: "{project}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
       endpoints.MapRazorPages();
  });
```

I added 'project' in front.

This works fine when navigating between the home, privacy, and every other page I created.

```
<a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a> // This hyperlink works fine.
// Returns: www.mydomain.com/myUniqueProjectName/Home/Privacy
```

The problem is when navigating to 'Log in' or 'Register' page (provided by the identity template) that part of the URL just gets deleted.

```
<a id="login" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a> // This hyperlink doesn't work
//becomes: www.mydomain.com/Identity/Account/Login 'myUniqueProjectName' is removed.
```

Now I solved it (kinda) but it's all hardcoded and doesn't make use of the `asp-action` and `asp-controller` tag-helpers.

The way I've done it now is like this:

```
// This is in the _Layout.cshtml (in the navigation)
<a class="nav-link text-dark" id="register" href="/@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["project"].ToString()/Account/Register" >Register</a>

// This is in the Register.cshtml (scaffolder template from asp.net core)
@page "/{project}/Account/Register"
```

The problem is, 1st it's hardcoded 2nd, I have to do all my pages hard coded like this because otherwise I can't navigate back to the pages I've created myself (the page refreshes but stays on the Register page). I think this is because it doesn't recognize the 'myUniqueProjectName' part in the URL.

Is there any better solution than to do all my routing hardcoded like this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all , you can implement it in a view then inherit from that view or use a partial view for this, then you don't need a piece of code in every page.
Secondly, you can get those attribute from your element using javascript and make your url and navigate.
However you can dig documents of this to see what's the proper way of implemnting this,you need to see if it worthed to put time on this or not